# File sending 404 to fpf but viewable in Browser

Tags: php

If you visit this page in the browser:  http://www.x-rates.com/d/TRY/table.html you can see that it works fine, but when I try to do `$doc = new DOMDocument(); $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.x-rates.com/d/TRY/table.html');` it returns 404. I have also tried doing `file_get_contents()` and sending the html to DOMDocument that way, but no luck. Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 4):

404 looks like the standard response code you've given for the URL:

```
$ curl -I http://www.x-rates.com/d/TRY/table.html
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 01 Aug 2011 12:23:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.19
Content-Type: text/html
```

You can acquire the HTTP response body and load it with DomDocument as a string.

This can be done with [`file_get_contents`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and setting the [`ignore_errors` HTTP context option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php). Example code:

```
$url = 'http://www.x-rates.com/d/TRY/table.html';

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'ignore_errors'=> true,
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

The page is returning a 404, and I believe it is doing this deliberately to make it harder to scrape it. I found this on their site:

> Fetching data with tools such as PHP, LWP, Java and Microsoft controls for example are not permitted

You might want to double-check that you are actually allowed to be doing what you are doing, I'm concerned you're potentially infringing copyright.

Comment: Where did you see this statement, I found nothing like that on this particular site, as I looked for it beforehand.

Comment: This limitation is implied by the terms of use and copyright page http://www.x-rates.com/copyright.html but I found that exact sentence on the developers page http://www.x-rates.com/developers.html