# PHP file_get_contents returning false

Tags: php, json

Maybe I've been sat here too long staring at this but WHY would `file_get_contents` return `false` here? I've cut and paste the URL and it works fine?

```
$url = "http://jobs.github.com/positions.json?search=" . $as_any . "&location=" .       $location;
// URL contains http://jobs.github.com/positions.json?search=Project Manager&location=London
var_dump($url);
$json = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($json);
$results = json_decode($json, TRUE);
var_dump($results);
exit;
```

**EDIT:**

I have checked for `allow_url_fopen` and its definitely on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem in getting contents/ files using file\_get\_contents from url or Problem in reverse geo coding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954220/problem-in-getting-contents-files-using-file-get-contents-from-url-or-problem-i)

Comment: None of the answers there seem to apply to this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = http_build_query(array('search'=>$as_any, 'location'=>$location));
$url = "http://jobs.github.com/positions.json?" . $query;
```

The problem is that you weren't URL-encoding the search term, which contains a space. The request was returning a 400 error from the server, which you'd have noticed if you had error reporting enabled.

Comment: In short, I love you..I did try doing $url = urlencode(....) but that didn't seem to work, whats the difference?

Comment: That will encode all the delimiter characters in the URL, so they won't be recognized as delimiters.

Answer (score 10):

In my case replace **file_get_contents()** on this simple function

```
function get_content($URL){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Brother You Saved My Life

Comment: Thanks, you saved me :)

Comment: no idea why but this totally works!

Answer (score 9):

You may need to enable allow_url_fopen in your php.ini

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

From the documentation:

> This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers that enable accessing
>   URL object like files.

Your server may be preventing you from opening a file located at a URL using file_get_contents.

Comment: Currently /etc/php.ini has allow_url_fopen = On

Comment: if file_get_contents() returning false then it could not read the file. If the value is NULL then the function itself is disabled.

Comment: Seems not true @NikhilMk, I got false but after enabling I got the data

Answer (score 5):

Probably allow_url_fopen in your php.ini: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Needs to be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if **file_get_contents** return **false** (not found) you should see if the url is **encoded**.

*example:*

> [http://test.net/демо/](http://test.net/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE/)

*Should be:*

> https://test.net/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE/